# checking if the value from a form field is over a certain number

Tags: javascript, webforms

I'm trying to write a simple check to see if a field is filled out with a value over 5. I have set up a form and put a few text fields in, one of those fields is going to require a dollar amount. I'm trying to check if this dollar amount is over 5 dollars, and if it's not to just pop up an alert to let the user know it is not over 5 dollars. The code I have so far is:

```
    <script>
    function validateForm()
    {
        var x=document.forms["amnt"]["Amount"].value;
        if (x<5)
        {
            alert("value is under 5 dollars!");
            return false;
        }

    }
</script>
```

This script works well for things like checking if a field is empty, but when I tried to change it to check the value of the field it just lets the user continue, even if the value is below 5.

can anyone provide any feedback on how to get this to check the actual numeric value of the field and see if it is above the 5 dollar amount?

EDIT: Thanks for all the answers, and they were all right, I'm a moron and forgot to include the onsubmit option for the form, so it wasnt doing any of my script. Now that that's fixed every good suggestions you guy had has worked out fine. Thanks for all the help, sorry about the mix up!

Comment: Can you show us where you call `validateForm`?

Comment: Try `var x=+document.forms["amnt"]["Amount"].value);` (With +)

Comment: @Mageek = `"6" < 5` is `false`.

Comment: @JosephSilber Yes. And `+"6" < 5` also

Comment: @Mageek - Sure. But if `"6" < 5` didn't work for him, neither would `+"6" < 5`. Chances are the event listener is not returning `false`.

Comment: Please remember to use onsubmit="return validateForm()" and return true if the test passes

Comment: @JosephSilber You're right. But he said that karaxuna's answer is perfect?! But `parseInt` and `+` are the same.

Comment: @Mageek - Sure is. There's something fishy going on here. I expect the OP to revisit this sometime soon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
var x=parseInt(document.forms["amnt"]["Amount"].value);
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you explained why.

Comment: element value is string, so it must be converted to number to compare to number

Answer (score 1):

You are getting a string when you call `.value`. You should compare integers, so use `parseInt()`.

```
<script>
    function validateForm()
    {
        var x = parseInt(document.forms["amnt"]["Amount"].value);
        if (x<5)
        {
            alert("value is under 5 dollars!");
            return false;
        }

    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd use parseInt with its second parameter set to 10, so it parses the input with radix 10.

```
var x=parseInt(document.forms["amnt"]["Amount"].value, 10);
```

If you omit the param, in some (older) browsers something like this could happen.

parseInt('09') == 0 (it's parsed octal, because of the leading 0)

parseInt('09', 10) == 9 (decimal is forced)

Comment: FYI, prepending a `+` is equivalent to `parseInt` with the radix set to `10`.

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
function validateForm()
{
    var x = parseInt(document.forms["amnt"]["Amount"].value);
    if (x && Number(x)<5)
    {
        alert("value is under 5 dollars!");
        return false;
    }

}
</script>
```